# send the app to Apple with in-app for approval for the first time

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I have an app already in store, for the next version I need to add in-app **purchase with auto renew**.
I have some questions about checking the receipt of the in-app.

1. Should TestFlight check the reception in front of a sandbox or production environment?
2. Is there any way to check the receipt in front of the production environment according to which the app is approved in the store?
3. When I send the app to Apple for approval for the first time, to what environment should it send the receipt for a sandbox or production test?

Answer (score 0):

find below answers to your questions:

1. No test flight won't check you need to submit and get approved your in-app purchase for live. You should submit proper information in the in-app purchase section that is required.
2. Please elaborate on this question.
3. When you sent the app for live you should use a live environment i.e Production.

Comment: are you sure that first time that you send new app version + in-app you need check receipt on production url and not sandbox? I know when you use sendbox url the time of in-app it shorts time. i.e. 30 day is 5 min
if you use production url apple wait 30 day before they approve app and in-app when they see that subscription renew?

Comment: You can submit app to store using manual option means Manually live and after approval of in app purchase you can make it live so it won’t affect your release as well.